# function XXX(txid) { shell.openExternal('url'+txid) } take 2 min to open my link

Tags: javascript

hello I have a PB with the function

```
function XXX(txid) {
shell.openExternal('url'+txid)
}
```

When I call it, i see that chrome receive instruction but nothing happens until I wait 2min.

So the link always open 2min after i've clicked on my call button.

(button is on an electron app and its a call to open a link on default macos browser. worked fine few days before)

Comment: "[W]orked fine few days before" this is a great red flag that you've changed something somewhere else in your code that's broken this.

Comment: code hasn't changed